# How do I add a new Arabic vowel-sign in the PUA area of a font?

Tags: unicode, fonts, arabic, fontforge

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, with FontForge compiled from the Git repo as of 31 
July.

I'm trying to add a vowel-sign to an Arabic font, Graph, by Future Soft Egypt:
http://openfontlibrary.org/en/font/graph
I have added glyphs where the Unicode code-point already exists (eg peh, 
U+067E), and that works fine.  I am now trying to add a vowel sign where no 
Unicode code-point exists - it is a "damma with tail", used by some writers in 
Swahili to mean "o".

I decided to put it in the PUA at U+E909, and copied the font's damma (U+064F) 
and added a tail:
http://kevindonnelly.org.uk/swahili/images/dammas.png
I generated the font, and set up the keyboard to emit that character.

The glyph comes up OK, but there are two problems, as can be seen here:
http://kevindonnelly.org.uk/swahili/images/output.png
showing at top "bubu", using the original damma, and at bottom "bobo", using 
the new damma-with-tail.

(1) The damma-with-tail is too far to the left, even though the anchor points 
in FF have not been moved.

(2) Worse, the damma-with-tail means that only the isolated versions of the 
consonant glyphs get used - in the second line the two bs should be joined, as 
in the first line.

I'm not sure whether this is a function of using the PUA, or whether it's due 
to my missing some step I need to take in FF (eg the Encoding -> Add Encoding 
Slots that needs to be done for the consonants), but if anyone could shed some 
light on how to fix the two problems, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: For the problem (i), you might have to take care of z-dimension so that the letter doesn't get moved from the collective center.

Comment: Thanks for that, though I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: U+064F has the Unicode properties `General_Category=Nonspacing_Mark` and `Joining_Type=Transparent`. Re: (2) How does it render when putting ZWJs (U+200D) before/after the BEHs?